Web worker only from the cache in Javascript
The stockfish chess engine is 64MB big.
I need to ensure that nobody downloads this over a network connection.
(only allow over wifi or ethernet)
I am running this code to check if the connection is cellular and if the file is not already in the cache. If so, don't use the big file, otherwise, use it:
function LoadEngine() {
if(navigator.connection.type=='cellular'&&!IsCached) return;
stockfish=new Worker('//www.mysite.com/stockfish-16.1-single.js')
}

IsCached is global and is set beforehand with this code:
async function SetCached()
{
try {
await fetch('//www.linguashop.com/course/java/stockfish-16.1-single.js',{
method:'Head',cache:'only-if-cached',mode:'same-origin'});
IsCached=true;
} 
catch (error) {IsCached=false}
}

Testing indicated that the logic worked ok.
On a mobile, cellular was detected and whether or not the file was in the cache was also detected ok.
And yet...the data usage clearly indicated that the big file had been downloaded.
(i.e. the cached file was not used).
Is there is a reliable way of only using a cache file for a web worker and not allowing a download?
i.e.:
stockfish=new Worker('//www.mysite.com/stockfish-16.1-single.js','cache-only');
stockfish=new Worker('//www.mysite.com/stockfish-16.1-single.js','no-download');


Sounds like a job for a ServiceWorker, where you'd manage the caching and fetching yourself.

Hello Kaiido. Could you provide an example?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers should get you covered. You'd catch from there only when not on data connection, and whenever you see a request to that file, you return the cached version. (But it's a bit weird the browser didn't cache it for you to begin with...)
